# Is it worth it to have resilience for rogues when fighing healers?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I play on 4.0.6 and I noticed that in a 1v1 vs healers, if I don't kill them in the time period of stuns/silences they manage to get a heal (especially paladins). After the heal, I will most likely not be able to kill them. They can then slowly kill me as a I recuperate.

So my question is: Is it a better idea to change some of my PvP items that give resilience with some PvE items that don't give resilience but other stats that improve my damage
 (such as hit rating, etc.), since if I don't kill them within the crowd control time I'm done for anyway.

Comment: Isn't hit rating irrelevant in pvp? I thought you have a flat chance to hit and nothing will increase or decrease it.

Comment: @MrSmooth Not true at all. The hit cap is lower for PVP because your targets are the same level as you (instead of bosses which are 3 levels higher), but you still need hit in PVP.

Comment: your hit should be capped in pvp even if you are wearing full resilience pvp gear, you do not want to see a miss on a key ability

Comment: @Mr. smooth as far as I'm tracking Hit applies to PvE only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, resilience lowers the amount of damage you take from enemy players, increasing your chance to survive counterattacks by any enemy who is no longer CC'ed, so I'd say, **Yes resilience is still important when fighting against a healer.**

You *could* swap out some Res gear for extra dps or what have you, but frankly a superior player would likely benefit more from taking less damage rather than doing more. It gives you more time to adjust to the battle, survive until your next important cooldown, or otherwise take advantage of a key point in the situation.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, fighting healers should always be about reducing their healing (I'm thinking wound poison here) and interrupting heals (use Mind-Numbing poison as there are few instant cast heals - especially on pallies, so this makes the cast take longer, so you've got more time to kick).  PvP against healers for non-healing classes is almost always an endurance question (and waiting for a mistake to capitalize on).

I would honestly concentrate more on steady damage so that you can get them down into burst range, rather than blowing all your CC options up-front and hoping you can make it to 0 before your CC wears off (or gets trinketed).

You've got a number of options at resetting the fight outside of the normal stun / silence moves - Cloak of Shadows should allow you to survive longer against a healer (as most healers are going to deal magic damage); Vanish will allow you to start a fight over and get another Kidney Shot / Cheap Shot combo, or another silencing Garrote.  Restarting a fight is usually in your favor if you can start your opponent at less than max health and mana.  Get in his face and Gouge him once your stuns and such have worn off and rebuild some energy / get a tick or two of recuperate.